# Modular OSGi Vaadin Application - Resources from extensions

Tags: resources, osgi, vaadin, modular

I am trying to build a modular web application, that consists of a main application and pluggable extensions (sub-applications) using Vaadin + OSGi.

To get started into the topic and try out different ways I followed this article: 
[*Modular and dynamic application with OSGi and Apache iPOJO*](https://vaadin.com/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Modular+and+dynamic+application+with+OSGi+and+Apache+iPOJO)

Using this approach a question came up:

How could I enable the extensions to include **their own resources in their own bundle** and use them in the development/implementation of the extension just as usually done in Vaadin ([*Book of Vaadin - 4.4. Images and Other Resources*](https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/application.resources.html) ?

Has anyone experiences regarding this?

Thank you in advance for any help!